# How to make active tab with refresh page

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have tab for showing data. A tab by defaul data from specific category and other category data showing in different tab. I am just trying when someone search a product and if that product belong to 3rd tab then after refresh this tab should be active without click.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show code related to your tabs. You will likely need to update url hash on tabs change and use the hash value on refresh to activate tab

Comment: You can use url hash or cookies depending on the conditions. Share your tab code for detailed answer